# Import OpenStreetMap data to Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, openstreetmap

Given an OpenStreetMap path (such as [this railroad track](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1948000)), is there a simple way to convert the points representing the railroad track from OpenStreetMap to a Google Maps `GMSPath`?

For example, if it was possible to download all the points (nodes) on the path from OpenStreetMaps and then convert these nodes to Google's [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm), then one could construct a `GMSPath` with the pathFromEncodedPath initializer.

Comment: You can export data from OpenStreetMap http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export and import data to google maps from here https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?hl=en

Comment: The problem is that a path (`relation`) in OpenStreetMap really consists of many `ways` which again are comprised of `nodes`. So, the question is really about how to simply string the `nodes` together to a single path.

Comment: How to convert a relation to a list of lat and lons is a really different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First - to get the OSM's relation *including* all ways and nodes, append a "/full" to your relation link using the API; "http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1948000/full"

I'm not sure if Verma's solution will work out the box with OpenStreetMap's exported XML. However, a more brute-force way could be to create a script that will parse the XML and iterate over each node element, taking its "lat" and "lon" property, and applying the algorithm described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm to create an ASCII string that can be read into the Google Maps iOS SDK.